# python Flask and MPR121 reading on raspberry PI

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I am trying to write a little program, which reads out MPR121's status with Adafruit MPR121 python library (capacitive touch with Raspberry PI 2), and this status can be get via a simple GET method.

The problem is that, I can't manage to create its reading thread: as example of the MPR121 shows, I have to use at least a while loop - or just do one measurement. Example:

```
import time
from flask import Flask

import Adafruit_MPR121.MPR121 as MPR121

#you have to give the static URL path and physical path on your machine
#after then you can reach some static files
# this is essential!!

app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path="/client", static_folder="/home/pi/asd/client")
cap = MPR121.MPR121()
#enabling some test issues
TEST = False

@app.route('/read')
def read():
    if TEST:
        return "asd"
    else:
        current_touched = cap.touched()
        return current_touched


@app.route('/')
def root():
    #This is the root path, just sent back a static webpage
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

As you see, I'd get the status of the MPR121 with a standard get method (flask answers errorCode 500). How can I solve this problem?

Answer:

```
 * Serving Flask app "flask_main"
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
asd
[2018-04-09 21:48:02,189] ERROR in app: Exception on /read [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/pi/alapitvany/flask_main.py", line 28, in read
    current_touched = cap.touched()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_MPR121/MPR121.py", line 179, in touched
    t = self._i2c_retry(self._device.readU16LE, MPR121_TOUCHSTATUS_L)
AttributeError: 'MPR121' object has no attribute '_device'
192.168.1.175 - - [09/Apr/2018 21:48:02] "GET /read HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source the MPR121 library (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MPR121/blob/master/Adafruit_MPR121/MPR121.py#L92) indicates that you need to call `cap.begin()` before asking whether it's been touched. That's where `_device` (in the bottom of that stack trace) gets set.

Comment: Correct answer, I forget to instantiate the MPR121 library. On the other side, this illustrated solution is bad: flask needs special context switching, which means above the code won't work.